# Append array on 'x', 'y', 'z' iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid from an API with random grid sizes. I might not ask this properly (hence why I couldn't find what I needed) but what I need is to be able to 'label' array **equally**. Here is the scenario; An array length of 10.

```
0: { id: 1, title: "First Element" }
1: { id: 3, title: "Second Element" }
2: { id: 5, title: "Third Element" }
3: { id: 7, title: "Forth Element" }
4: { id: 9, title: "Fifth Element" }
5: { id: 11, title: "Sixth Element" }
6: { id: 13, title: "Seventh Element" }
7: { id: 15, title: "Eigth Element" }
8: { id: 17, title: "Nineth Element" }
9: { id: 19, title: "Tenth Element" }
```

I want to append the objects to add a new property named `class` for instance;

I need `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` to be `col-2` and `4` to be `col-4` and same repeated for the remaining 
items. `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` to be `col-2` and `9` to be `col-4`.

But **equally** - cannot have a 1/2 unit followed by a full-width unit and need the last item to be full-width.

Desired outcome:

```
0: { id: 1, title: "First Element", class: 'col-2' }
1: { id: 3, title: "Second Element", class: 'col-2'}
2: { id: 5, title: "Third Element", class: 'col-2' }
3: { id: 7, title: "Forth Element", class: 'col-2' }
4: { id: 9, title: "Fifth Element", class: 'col-4' }
5: { id: 11, title: "Sixth Element", class: 'col-2' }
6: { id: 13, title: "Seventh Element", class: 'col-2' }
7: { id: 15, title: "Eigth Element", class: 'col-2' }
8: { id: 17, title: "Nineth Element", class: 'col-2' }
9: { id: 19, title: "Tenth Element", class: 'col-4' }
10: { id: 21, title: "Last Element", class: 'col-4' }
```

Function:

```
this.renderContent = function() {
    if (this.retrievedNewsArticles == null || this.retrievedNewsArticles.length == 0) {
        $(contentContainerElement).html('<p class="inline-message">There is currently no data to display.</p>');
    } else {
        // The loop is here
        for (var i = 0; i < this.retrievedNewsArticles.length; i++) {
            this.addUnit(this.retrievedNewsArticles[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Plugin suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want the output to be?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var arr = [
    { id: 1, title: "First Element" },
    { id: 3, title: "Second Element" },
    { id: 5, title: "Third Element" },
    { id: 7, title: "Forth Element" },
    { id: 9, title: "Fifth Element" },
    { id: 11, title: "Sixth Element" },
    { id: 13, title: "Seventh Element" },
    { id: 15, title: "Eigth Element" },
    { id: 17, title: "Nineth Element" },
    { id: 19, title: "Tenth Element" },
    { id: 21, title: "Last Element" }
];

var lastElIndex = arr.length - 1;

var test = arr.map((item, index) => {
    // edit per OP request
    if ( (index + 1) % 5 === 0) {
        item['className'] = 'col-4';
    }
    //if ( (index + 1)  % 5 === 0) {
    //    return { id: item.id, title: item.title, className: "col-4" };
    } else if (index === lastElIndex) {
        return { id: item.id, title: item.title, className: "col-4" };
    } else {
        return { id: item.id, title: item.title, className: "col-2" };
    }
});
```

What we're doing here is iterating through the array and mapping the className attribute to each item depending on if whether or not (index + 1) mod 5 is true or not.

Edit: added the last element requirement. I missed that on my first read through. My apologizes.

Comment: In addition, you should add a check for the last item in the array and force a "col-4" value for class name. It's in the requirement.

Comment: Well spotted @Brian - I could handle that. Although I'm trying to think of scenario where there could be a `col-2`, `col-4` & `col-2` pattern as that would leave a gap next to the `col-2`.

Comment: my edit will cover the last element situation for you

Comment: if you're going to downvote, comment as to why. this answer solves his problem, so I'm not sure what yours is.

Comment: @KyleRichardson upvoted to balance it out. This should be the answer imo

Comment: Solved my problem. I just modified your answer slightly so it adds a new property `if ( (index + 1) % 5 === 0) { item['className'] = 'col-4'; }`. Will be better if you edit your answer with that for future visitors.

Comment: @Devrim: I included your edit. Glad your problem is resolved!

Comment: Nice! However, Murphy's law. If the length is an odd number, the logic don't work. E.g. 7, 0-3, 5 will be `col-2`, 4 and 6 as the last index will be `col-4`. So the pattern breaks. A half-unit floating between full width elements. To tackle this, I check if the length is an odd number. Make the odd number a `col-4` and slice it from the array.

Comment: `if(isOdd(myarray.length)) { var odd =myarray[0]; odd['className'] = 'col-4'; myarray.splice(0, 1); }`

Comment: logic can always be adapted for different scenarios once you understand the premise. :)